# PHP Throwing Odd Error

Tags: php, html

I keep getting the following error message when executing this code:
 
 **Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\HoneysProject\function.php on line 1178**

Line 1178 is referring to the following line of code:

**$number_photos = $photo_exists->num_rows ;**

Not sure exactly why it is throwing this error because it's a duplicate of a line of code I've been using pretty frequently on this project.  Doesn't seem to have any real influence on the code running to completion since I proceed to the successful output.  Would Just like the error message to stop popping up.

The following is the source code in it's entirety:

```
function create_album()
{
    try
    {
        if( isset( $_SESSION['session_id'] ) && $_SESSION['permissions'] ==  0  )
        {
            if( isset( $_POST['album_name'] ) && ( file_exists( $_FILES['cover_photo']['tmp_name'] ) || is_uploaded_file($_FILES['cover_photo']['tmp_name'] ) ) )
            {
                $db = honneyconnect( ) ;
                if( mysqli_connect_error() )
                {
                    throw new Exception( "Could not connect to the database") ;  
                }
                else
                {
                    $unique = false ;
                    while( $unique == false )
                    {
                        $key = rand( )  ;
                        $query = "select * from albums where album_id = '".$key."'";  
                        $album_exists = $db->query( $query ) ;
                        $number_albums = $album_exists->num_rows ;
                        if( $number_albums == 0 )
                        {
                            $unique = true ;
                        }
                    }
                if( !mkdir( "c:\\wamp\\www\\honeysproject\\".$_POST['album_name']  ) )
                {
                    throw new Exception( "Failed to create the album.  Please try again." ) ;
                }
                else
                {
                    $file_name = $_FILES["cover_photo"]["name"] ;
                    if( !move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cover_photo"]["tmp_name"], "C:/wamp/www/HoneysProject/".$_POST['album_name']."/" . $_FILES["cover_photo"]["name"]) )
                    {
                        throw new Exception( "There was a problem uploading the file" ) ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $query = 'insert into albums values ("'.$key.'","'.$_POST['album_name'].'", "'.$_FILES['cover_photo']['name'].'")';
                        $album = $db->query( $query ) ;
                        if( !$album )
                        {
                            throw new Exception( "Failed to create the ".$_POST['album_name']." album.  Please check your input and try again." ) ;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $unique = false ;
                            while( $unique == false )
                            {
                                $picture_key = rand();
                                $query = "select * from photos where photo_id = '".$picture_key."'" ;
                                $photo_exists = $db->query( $query ) ;
                                $number_photos = $photo_exists->num_rows ;
                                if( $number_photos == 0 ) 
                                {
                                    $unique = true ;
                                }


                            }
                            $query = "insert into photos values ('".$key."', '".$picture_key."', '".$file_name."')" ;
                            $picture_query = $db->query( $query ) ;
                            if( !$picture_query ) 
                            {

                                throw new Exception( "Failed to add photo to the photos table.  Please check your syntax and try again." ) ;

                            }   
                            else
                            {
                                echo "<table><tr><td><img src='/HoneysProject/".$_POST['album_name']."/".$_FILES['cover_photo']['name']."'></td><td><a class ='button' href='/HoneysProject/uploadphotos.php?album_id=".$key."'>Upload Photos</a><br><a class='button' href='/HoneysProject/albumedit.php?album_id=".$key."'>Edit Album</a></td></tr></table>" ;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }


            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<div class="data_entry">
                        <form id="new_album" method="post" action="createalbum.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="50000000" />
                        <table>
                        <tr><td>Album Name:</td><td><input type="text" size="10" name="album_name" /></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Choose a Default Photo:</td><td><input type="file" name="cover_photo" id="photo" /></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit Data" /></td></tr>
                        </table>

                        </form></div>' ;
        }
    }
}
catch( Exception $error ) 
{
    echo "<div class='error'>".$error."</div>" ;
    echo '<div class="data_entry">
                        <form id="new_album" method="post" action="createalbum.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="50000000" />
                        <table>
                        <tr><td>Album Name:</td><td><input type="text" size="10" name="album_name" value="'.$_POST['album_name'].'"/></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Choose a Default Photo:</td><td><input type="file" name="cover_photo" id="photo" /></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit Data" /></td></tr>
                        </table>

                        </form></div>' ;

}
}
```

Comment: well ... is `$photo_exist` an object?

Comment: What happens when you var_dump($number_photos), is it actually an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to an unsuccessful query.

I wonder why you are manually generating the entities keys? Doesn't your DBMS support auto incremented keys or sequences?

Comment: I'm currently using phpMyAdmin and I'm not sure how to set my keys to auto increment or auto generate a unique key.  So I've been attempting to manually perform the task myself.

Comment: auto increment is very easy in phpMyAdmin for sql tables. It is simply a property you can set on the column when creating it. You must first set it as a primary key, then the option becomes available to auto increment I believe (Its a drop down menu that is by default blank). <- From my version of phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the query failed and `$photo_exists` is not an object it's either `null` or `false`. As per the documentation [mysqli::query](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query):

- Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

You should check for errors before trying to use an object returned by the `mysqli` functions.

```
$photo_exists = $db->query($query) ;
if($number_photos) {
    $number_photos = $photo_exists->num_rows ;
}
```

Or even:

```
if($photo_exists = $db->query($query)) {
    $number_photos = $photo_exists->num_rows ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$photo_exists is not an object and is most likely null. Double check where you initialize it to ensure the capitalization and spelling is correct.

Also you should add some debugging print statements to check the state of $photo_exists just before you try to use it, you will most likely be surprised that it doesn't contain what you want.

you can use var_dump($photo_exists) to try to help you output the object.

Comment: So just out of curiosity then why does $album_exists in the beginning of the code where I'm generating the key for the album return an object?  This should be throwing the same error but it isn't assuming I generate a unique key.

Comment: If you output the query you are doing to the DB and copy paste the output and try it on PHPMYADMIN, does it return an error or does it return successfully? You may need to double check out SQL Statement format. If you don't understand what I mean I can try to rephrase, simply ask :)

Comment: @NoobWebDev  no problem. Also check out my comment on the accepted answer about auto increment using PHPMYADMIN. I am glad I could help you; no matter how minor.